# Where do web-crawlers get their list of sites to crawl?

Tags: web-crawler

I know all of the basic steps taken by search engines to deliver search results to the user, but there is one thing I do not understand, and that is the physical compiling of the list of sites to crawl.  How do programs like googlebot get the actual list of websites that they will search?

Answer (score 0):

That will likely vary from crawler to crawler, but the most likely place to start would be domain registrations.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a massive amount of bandwidth if it's constantly querying DNS servers?

Comment: Again, it varies from crawler to crawler. Pure supposition on my part, but once the initial crawl is "seeded", the crawler finds other sites to crawl and enters them into a database to crawl at a later time. Many sites allow you to explicitly submit a site to be crawled for inclusion in the search engine, putting the responsiblity on the user rather than the crawler. For example [Bing](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/submit-site-url) or [Google](http://www.google.com/submityourcontent/). It all depends upon the crawler.

Comment: There are also services that allow feeds or searches of newly registered domains.

Answer (score 0):

Search engines like google often are feed with new content by discovering it from other sites.

For example, if you have a website which is crawled already and links to a new website. When Google comes to your site and sees the new site, it starts also indexing the new one.

On the other hand, you can also ping Google with new websites to be indexed, so it's not only passive but also active.